# Use Tbb library in Clion IDE

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cmake, clion, tbb

I am trying run this code in Clion IDE. I want to use TBB library. I use C++ 11.

```
#include “tbb/blocked_range.h”
#include “tbb/parallel_for.h”

#include <vector>

const size_t SIZE = 10000000;

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> myArray(SIZE);

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, SIZE),
    [&myArray](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t> &r)
    {
        for (size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); i++)
            Calculate(myArray[i]);
    });

    return 0;
}
```

from command line :

`g++ task1.cpp -o task1 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -ltbb`

this code work perfect.

But in Clion not.

I think problem in my CMakeLists.txt file.

What Clion tell me:

```
CMakeFiles/parallel.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `run':
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:148: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_reduce.h:148: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
CMakeFiles/parallel.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata+0xa0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
CMakeFiles/parallel.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata+0x1c8): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
CMakeFiles/parallel.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `tbb::task_group_context::task_group_context(tbb::task_group_context::kind_type, unsigned long)':
/usr/include/tbb/task.h:441: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
```

...

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6) 
project(parallel) 
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fopenmp -ltbb") 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp main.cpp) 
add_executable(parallel ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

How can I change my CMakeLists.txt file or I should do some else? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Use `include_directories("PATH/TO/TBB_INCLUDE") `

Comment: the same, not work

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to make sure your TBB is setup correctly.

The current version of TBB is oneTBB. It is an open source project supported by Intel. The older version of TBB is [here](https://github.com/wjakob/tbb), but it sends you to the newer version, oneTBB. So, it is better to stay with the newer oneTBB.

There are two ways to get oneTBB: Either from the oneTBB Github source [here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB) (which is explained [here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/master/INSTALL.md)) or from Intel oneTBB [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onetbb.html).

I preferred Intel, since it provides a GUI installer (also provides apt for Linux). After installing oneTBB using the GUI, you have to set the environment which is explained [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-onetbb/top.html).

You should test you oneTBB settings by a simple code. Above web page [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-onetbb/top.html) provides a sample code, which I wrapped with a main function for your convenience (note the included header `oneapi/tbb.h`):

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "oneapi/tbb.h"

int main(){
int sum = oneapi::tbb::parallel_reduce(oneapi::tbb::blocked_range<int>(1,101), 0,
   [](oneapi::tbb::blocked_range<int> const& r, int init) -> int {
      for (int v = r.begin(); v != r.end(); v++  ) {
     init += v;
      }
      return init;
   },
   [](int lhs, int rhs) -> int {
      return lhs + rhs;
   }
);

std::cout << sum << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Compile it with (as explained [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-onetbb/top.html)):

```
g++ -o test test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags tbb)
```

If your system (gcc, oneTBB and others) are setup properly, this should work.

When it comes to CLion, you will need `CMakeLists.txt` file. There are examples in the oneTBB GitHub page [here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/tree/master/examples). Open for example test_all folder with CLion as if you are opening a project. It should build from there. By looking at the cmake files of the example project, you can create you own cmake file.

**Update:**

1. Please look at [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Threading-Building/std-execution-par-error/m-p/1388878#M15091) post and posts there from Intel for oneTBB.
2. I have prepared sample files for old TBB and oneTBB [here](https://github.com/bariserkus/tbb_setup) for building with both command line GCC and CMAKE. CMAKE is the one required for CLion.

For CLion and the old version of TBB this would be a basic CMAKE file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.xx)
project(testtbb)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(TBB REQUIRED)
add_executable(testtbb_long.out testtbb_long.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testtbb_long.out tbb)
```

Note that for linking the TBB library to the defined executable, you need to use `target_link_libraries` as:

```
target_link_libraries(executable-name.out tbb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a cmake test to find libtbb, which also sets the correct variables.

There is a FindTBB on github, which you can try to use.